# No toma valor de un input de los otros si

Tags: laravel, input

Estoy enviando datos de un input a un controlador, todo me funciona bien menos con 1 campo, sin embargo me aparece en el dd.

$lims_customer_data = $request->all();

```
    $lims_customer_data['is_active'] = true;

    
    $lims_customer_data['name'] = $lims_customer_data['fullname'];



    Customer::create($lims_customer_data);
```

Vista:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="fullname" name="fullname" placeholder="XXXXXXXX" data-msg="Ingrese su Nombre" aria-describedby="button-addon2">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="num_doc" name="num_doc" placeholder="XXXXXXXX" data-msg="Ingrese el Número de DNI" aria-describedby="button-addon2">
              <input type="text" id="cuil" name="cuil" hidden>
```

Error:

General error: 1364 Field 'num_doc' doesn't have a default value

Probé:

```
dd($lims_customer_data);

        Customer::create($lims_customer_data);
```

y me devuelve

```
array:12 [▼
  "_token" => "zQO9k7lvRNahklt4tSv4A3xwUQSMudOSXZjXxqVp"
  "num_doc" => "NUMERO INGREADO"
  "cuil" => "ESTO SE GENERA SOLO POR ESO EL HIDDEN"
  "fullname" => "NOMBRE INGRESADO"
  "is_active" => true
  "name" => "NOMBRE INGRESADO REPETIDO que se obtiene porque cambio el nombre del request para coincidir con la base de datos."
]
```

en el DD todo funciona correctamente, pero no cuando quito el dd no se porque no me recolecta el num_doc y lo almacena en la tabla del mismo nombre.

Vale aclarar que el código lo resumí pero hay mas campos los cuales si son recolectados y almacenados sin problema.

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado, mi problema es que cuando edite la ultima vez el Model cambié por error el campo de num_doc por nro_doc. no coincidia con el nombre de columna en la tabla.